# Ubuntu 15.04 Installation Problem, HP Envy 15

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, uefi, hp

This is my first system with UEFI....
Laptop name: HP Envy 15 Notebook PC (with Touchscreen)....
OS installed: Windows 10, self installed ....
Processor: Intel i7-5500U @ 2.40GHz (4 CPUs) ....
Ram: 8 GB ....
It has Intel HD Graphics 5500 and Nvidia Geforce GTX 850M .... I created a LiveUSB of Ubuntu 15.04. md5 was fine. it worked on a friends PC. But in my laptop, I can boot from it. I select "try Ubuntu without installing" Then this happens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PIny.jpg Then this happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf61B.jpg After this Ubuntu regular boot image starts (the purple screen with Ubuntu logo) never to move ahead.

Edit:
I use the nomodeset option. Boot the LiveCD/LiveUSB .. when you get to the screen where it ask if you want to install or try Ubuntu, leave "Try Ubuntu" highlighted and hit e....... Change quiet splash --

make it end with:-

quiet splash nomodeset

Comment: Can anybody help?

Comment: My initial suggestion is to use the `nomodeset` kernel parameter. When the boot options appear, highlight the one you want and then hit `e` to edit the options. You can add `nomodeset` to the kernel options line and continue the boot. This is not 100% guaranteed to work, though; it's just my initial suggestion.

Comment: @Rod Smith How do I add nomodeset to kernel options line?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Ubuntu's now booted.

Comment: @user68186 I believe a lot of other users will have this problem. There is no other place where this problem is solved. Why not let this question live?

Comment: @Fabby Thanks for sorting it out. I saw your invitation to chat quite late. I will catch you next time. Cheers! :)